# Weird BufferedReader behavior for a huge file

Tags: java, string, csv, split

I am getting a very weird error. So, my program read a csv file.

Whenever it comes to this line:

```
"275081";"cernusco astreet, milan, italy";NULL
```

I get an error:

[image]

In the debug screen, I see that the BufferedReader read only

```
"275081";"cernusco as
```

That is a part of the line. But, it should read all of the line.
[image]

What bugs me the most is when I simply remove that line out of the csv file, the bug disappear! The program runs without any problem. I can remove the line, maybe it is a bad input or whatever; but, I want to understand why I am having this problem.

For better understanding, I will include a part of my code here:

```
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userFile));
        reader.readLine(); // skip first line
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = line.split("\";\"");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(stripPunctionMark(fields[0]));
            String location = fields[1];
            if (location.contains("\";")) { // When there is no age. The data is represented as "location";NULL. We cannot split for ";" here. So check for "; and split.
                location = location.split("\";")[0];
                System.out.printf("Added %d at %s\n", id, location);
                people.put(id, new Person(id, location));
                numberOfPeople++;
            }
            else {
                int age = Integer.parseInt(stripPunctionMark(fields[2]));
                people.put(id, new Person(id, location, age));
                System.out.printf("Added %d at: %s age: %d \n", id, location, age);
                numberOfPeople++;
            }
```

Also, you can find the csv file [here](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/) or here is a short version of the part that I encountered the error:

```
"275078";"el paso, texas, usa";"62"
"275079";"istanbul, eurasia, turkey";"26"
"275080";"madrid, n/a, spain";"29"
"275081";"cernusco astreet, milan, italy";NULL
"275082";"hacienda heights, california, usa";"16"
"275083";"cedar rapids, iowa, usa";"22"
```

Comment: Have you tried substituting "NULL" with a valid string?

Comment: I just changed the line to : "275081";"cernusco as
treet, milan, italy";"15" But the problem still exists. There are a lot of NULL before this line. And, my program handled them well. Just this particular line drives my crazy.

Comment: It seems that there is a hidden character just after the `as`. Can you extract that part of the file and view it with a hex dump?

Comment: Look at the file with a hex editor - are there any strange characters on that line?

Comment: Which line is 44? Is there empty line at the bottom of the file?

Comment: That works. I deleted the `as` part and changed it to something different. However, in the future I can encounter more hidden character. And they may not be as obvious as this one. How can I avoid them? Why do they even exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with `BufferedReader.` It doesn't even appear in the stack trace.

It has to do with your failure to check the result and length of the array returned by `String.split().` Instead you are just assuming the input is well-formed, with at least three columns in each row, and you have no defences if it isn't.

Comment: Is there a Java Library that do all this thing for us? For example, just give in a file and it will gives out a Map or Arrays.